# JDBC Oracle error: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am getting below error while fetching record from ResultSet.Please could you help to resole this sissue.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.ava:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1066)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3716)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1015)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:979)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:579)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you tried to look for something? https://www.google.pl/search?q=ORA-12592&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_xtIWPe-G8-v8wfm9YHYAg

Answer (score 2):

**Root Cause:**

- Due to a defect or configuration issue in the operating environment.
- May be a firewall was intermittently interrupting database requests on the network which led to this exception.

   More help: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1673903

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround has been proven to resolve the issue (in most cases) until the patch can be applied, but with a warning and important note:

Add this parameter to the `sqlnet.ora file` at BOTH the `origin (or client)` and at the `Database server / instance`:

> SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT=n

- Where `n is a value in seconds`. The setting itself, and not the value, should resolve this issue, so a relatively high setting should eliminate this problem but with no impact to normal functions.

> E.g.
>
> SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT=60000